Anticollision beacon light flash frequency, and relationship to strobe lights, for the Embraer E195LR
This question is very similar to one about the A340, but I wonder instead about the following regarding the Embraer E195LR:

Does the anticollision beacon light on top of the fuselage flash at fixed rate for all E195LRs, or could there be changes due to parts replacement?
If yes to the former, what is that flashing frequency? (Regulations give wide ranges for the allowable flash frequency)
Is there a fixed pattern relating that light to the aircraft's strobe lights? (Cf. comments to the A340 question)

(The "asking good questions" page for Aviation SE encourages explanations as to why the question/answer might be useful to others: In my case, I'm attempting to do some temporal synchronization based on (incidental) observation of said light.)

I have one idea for you; you can get videos of that plane on YouTube and count the flashes or do something similar to get the frequency.
